# Using docker-compose, how to get access to a database outside of a container

Tags: docker, networking, localhost

I am using docker-compose to run multiple containers (a webserver, daemon, and database). I would also like to be able to access a local postgres database, running on localhost on port 5432. How do I configure the dock-compose.yaml file. Each service is using the network below. Please let me know if I can supply any more additional details. Thank you in advance.

```
networks:
  docker_example_network:
    driver: bridge
    name: docker_example_network
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change your driver from `bridge` to `host`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Host networking doesn't work if you're using Docker Desktop, and isn't a best practice even if you're on a native-Linux system.  You also can't both use host networking and also connect to other containers using Docker networking.